# Image Map Not displaying Clickable Links

Tags: html, dictionary

Trying to get an image map to work and can't see where my coding is off!

```
<img src="images/lazyweb/stores.png"  border="0" usemap="#storemap" />
<map name="storemap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="96,155,343,326"      href="https://www.etsy.com">
    <area shape="rect" coords="414,155,663,327"     href="https://www.amazon.co.uk">
    <area shape="rect" coords="743,153,986,326"     href="https://www.ebay.co.uk">
</map>
```

I've used Dreamweaver to generate the co-ordinates, and that gives a visible template over the image, so I'm confident that the co-ordinates are ok (famous last words), but the displayed image just doesn't have any clickable links.

Comment: It doesn't seem wrong if you are sure coords are ok but it's difficult to help you in any way without the actual image. If you cannot publish that image replace it with something else.

Comment: Thanks for getting back... 
Yes a full image address would have been of more help... sorry!!

[https://lazycarrot.co.uk/images/lazyweb/stores.png]

_hoping I've got the text formatting right on that_ - Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Some script or CSS rules might be messing with you.

If it doesn't work you can always try positioning links using CSS.
see example below

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  width: 1124px;
  height: 426px;
  background:url('https://lazycarrot.co.uk/images/lazyweb/stores.png');
}

#img a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#img a.etsy { 
  top:140px;
  left:100px;
  width:220px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lazycarrot.co.uk/images/lazyweb/stores.png"  border="0" usemap="#storemap" />
<map name="storemap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="96,155,343,326"      href="https://www.etsy.com">
    <area shape="rect" coords="414,155,663,327"     href="https://www.amazon.co.uk">
    <area shape="rect" coords="743,153,986,326"     href="https://www.ebay.co.uk">
</map>

<div id="img">
  <a class="etsy"   href="https://www.etsy.com"></a>
  <a class="amazon" href="https://www.amazon.co.uk"></a>
  <a class="ebay"   href="https://www.ebay.co.uk"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that & sebastian ... I suspect the CSS/Script may be the issue - I'll try stripping some out and see if I can identify it... 
but positioning the links with CSS looks like a good option - I shall give that a go

Thanks - I'm considering that as problem solved...